# ConstraintLayout alignment with offset

Tags: android, margin, padding, offset, android-constraintlayout

I am using a ConstraintLayout with two views inside. An ImageView that varies in size depending on the image loaded and a View which acts as a custom made dropshadow for the Image. What I've been doing so far is adding 8dp padding to the ImageView and then aligning all of the edges of the View to the ImageViews, thereby making the View stick out 8dp underneath the ImageView.

Now for several reasons I don't want to keep the padding on the ImageView but I still want to achieve the same effect. So basically I would like to align the Left of the View to 8dp left of the Left of the ImageView (and the same for every other edge, right, top, bottom).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't use margins then?

Answer (score 3):

I´ve been having problems with this too, it seems ConstraintLayout does not support negative margins yet: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=235306.

In my case, I want a 20dp negative margin to a set of overlapping images on a header image. So far, I'm positioning an empty TextView below the guideline my header image is connected to, with a 20dp top margin and aligning my overlapping image views to that.